# Bird identification from Nepal

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I just stumbeld across a picture and wonder which species it is?

I took the below picture of a bird, probably a raptor, in mid-January 2011, 7 pm, on the Annapurna Trek in Nepal. My altitude was around 2000 m.

Since I took the picture a long time ago I cannot recall any information about the size.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image does not depict a predator, instead it's a scavenger. It's definitely a vulture, and by the looks of it a **[Griffon Vulture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griffon_vulture)**, which are a [common siting](https://www.zsl.org/conservation/regions/asia/vulture-conservation-in-india-and-nepal) in India.

The picture you provide is a bit grainy, and the apparently low-set sun colors the image somewhat yellow, but it does appear similar to below image of a Griffon vulture.

[image: Griffon vulture]
<sup>Griffon vulture. source: [Vulture conservation in India and Nepal](https://www.zsl.org/conservation/regions/asia/vulture-conservation-in-india-and-nepal)</sup>